# Disable subsection from navigation in beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm recently using the beamer theme *Warsaw*, which automatically displays subsections on the right of the headline. However, I want to **remove** the subsection from the navigation bar (marked red in the picture).

What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
\renewcommand{\insertsubsectionnavigation}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal}[3]{}
```

to your preamble

[image: y]

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}    

\usetheme{Warsaw}   

\renewcommand{\insertsubsectionnavigation}[1]{} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<    
\renewcommand{\insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal}[3]{} % added, used when compress <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}

\section{Basics}
    \begin{frame}{Basics}{First section}
        Start of the First section
    \end{frame}
    
\subsection{Workflow}
\begin{frame}{Workflow}{First subsection}
    In the First section
\end{frame}

\subsection{Datasets}
\begin{frame}{Datasets}{Second subsection}
    In the First section
\end{frame}

\subsection{Metrics}
\begin{frame}{Metrics}{Third subsection}
    In the First section
\end{frame}

\section{Papers}
    
\begin{frame}{Papers}{Second section}
    Start of the Second section
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

**Default behavior**

[image: z]

Comment: It works! thank you Simon